# How can I query the snapshot listener in Swift for Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When a new user installs the app for the first time the snapshot listener fetches all the documents from firestore database. This creates a lot of reads. I dont want that.

A new user should only see the documents created after his or her app install. So a query on timestamp ?

code for fetching the data from firestore.

```
func fetchData() {
    db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
```

Can i set a query on the addSnapshotListener. For example, query=show only the documents after a certain date.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with SwiftUI -- just Swift

Comment: You are right, i updated the question

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in creation timestamp that you can use in a query, so you'll have to add that yourself when you create the document. In fact, it's quite common to add two timestamps `createAt` and `updatedAt` and setting them to the [server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp).

With those in place, you can then query for only documents after now by [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) like this:

```
db.collection("users")
  .whereField("createAt", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp())
  .addSnapshotListener {...
```